# Foreach child in GameObject add child to list, adds more than it should

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, foreach

So my code right now

```
void UpdateList()
{
    foreach (Transform child in gameObject.transform) if (child.CompareTag("Food"))
    {
        FoodList.Add(child.gameObject);
    }
}

void EnableFood()
{
    UpdateList();
    foreach (GameObject Food in FoodList) if (Food.CompareTag("Food"))
    {
        Food.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        Food.gameObject.GetComponent<Food>().Claimed = false;
    }
}
```

What I have is the list of childs with the tag `Food`, this list is part of a "Farm".  Players can interact with the food in the farm, if a player collides with the `Food` object, that child gets removed from the list and set to inactive. And 20seconds later it gets set to active again to make it act like the food is respawning.

The problem with the code is that when I do `FoodList.Add(child.gameObject);` It doesn't add just the amount of childs in the parent, it adds way more.
From default there are 8 childs, when i run the method `UpdateList()` it adds 28.

--Edit showing what happens from start to end.

```
public List<GameObject> FoodList = new List<GameObject>();
void Update()
{
    UpdateList();
}

void UpdateList()
{
    foreach (Transform child in gameObject.transform) if (child.CompareTag("Food"))
    {
        FoodList.Add(child.gameObject);
    }
}
//At this point the list already has 14 objects in it.
//(Also made some minor changes that I made because I was frustrated the code didnt work..)

//Right now I have my parent GameObject
//that contains 8 childs with the tag Food in the editor.

//Now were moving to the Player his script.
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Object)
{
    if (Object.gameObject.tag == "Farm")
    {
        Farm = Object.gameObject.transform.parent;
        FoodListPlayer = Farm.GetComponent<FoodSpawn>().FoodList;
    }
}

//Here the collided object Food is set to inactive and removed from the list.
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision Object)
{
    if (Object.gameObject.tag == "Food")
    {
        Object.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        FoodListPlayer.Remove(Object.gameObject);
    }
}
```

I think that with the foreach loop it only adds as many childs as there are in the parent and that it stops adding if every child is in the list, that is probably what is going wrong on my end right now..

Comment: Have you checked the content of gameObject.transform in the UpdateList function ? Does it contain 28 items with tag "Food" ?

Comment: What is the content of the `CompareTag` method of the `Transform` class ?

Comment: @gobes This is a unity built in function, basically an equals check.

Comment: Please add other relevant code as well

Comment: Did you have a look in your food list on runtime to check the actual content? Like 28 is not a multiple of 8 so there needs to be something else going on.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot from the editor to show the object with the children?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/NQCHhpI.png

Comment: I guess you shouldn't update the list every frame like you do right now with Update. For the initial population of the list you can call `UpdateList` from `Start`. You actually should initialize it there too (the = new ...). Update the list only if there is an actual change and also check for duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is so simple, once you added the gameObject into the list, you are not removing that gaemObject from it's child. So whenever next time the UpdateList() called, it is adding all the gameObjects again. So either you have to remove the gameObject from it's child OR else you have to code it like one gameObject can be added into the List only once.

Hopefully this will help you...

Best,
 Hardik.

Comment: That's not really what i meant though. In short my list needs to be 1:1 of the active childs. But at the start of the game it already adds 28 childs to the list even though there are only 8 childs.

Comment: @Simon What you should probably do is to have two lists, one for the active and one for the inactive objects and move them accordingly. If you actually need a list other than the child list you get with `gameobject.transform`.